C++: What if a lambda expression captures a r-value by reference
I am trying to work with the lambda expression to wrap some functions to void() ones. The code is as follows:
class VoidFunctionWrapper
{
public:
    VoidFunctionWrapper()
    {
        function_ = []() {};
    }

    template <typename Function, typename... Args>
    VoidFunctionWrapper(Function &&function, Args &&...args)
    {
        wrap_function(std::forward<Function>(function), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void wrap_function(std::function<void()> function)
    {
        function_ = std::move(function);
    }

    template <typename Function, typename... Args>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Function>, std::function<void()>>, void>
    wrap_function(Function &&function, Args &&...args)
    {
        std::function<void()> function_lambda = [&]() mutable
        { function(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };

        wrap_function(function_lambda);
    }

    std::function<void()> get_wrapped_function()
    {
        return function_;
    }
private:
    std::function<void()> function_;
};

The class VoidFunctionWrapper wraps a function to a std::function<void()> instance. The key member function is:
    template <typename Function, typename... Args>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Function>, std::function<void()>>, void>
    wrap_function(Function &&function, Args &&...args)
    {
        std::function<void()> function_lambda = [&]() mutable
        { function(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };

        wrap_function(function_lambda);
    }

To state at the begining, I understand this function is not right because the capture list should use [=] instead of [&]. However, when using this "wrong" version of code with [&], I am really confused doing this test:
int main()
{
    // A test function to set a bool variable to true with a bool pointer
    // It changes the value and print the address

    std::function<void(bool *)> check = [](bool *ptr)
    { 
        std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
        *ptr = true; 
    };

    // Configure some tasks to execute
    
    std::vector<VoidFunctionWrapper> tasks_to_execute;
    std::deque<bool> check_list(5, false);
    for (size_t i_check = 0; i_check < check_list.size(); i_check++)
    {
        VoidFunctionWrapper temp_func = VoidFunctionWrapper(check, &(check_list[i_check]));
        tasks_to_execute.push_back(std::move(temp_func));
    }
    
    for (size_t i_check = 0; i_check < check_list.size(); i_check++)
    {
        tasks_to_execute[i_check].get_wrapped_function()();
    }

    for (size_t i_check = 0; i_check < check_list.size(); i_check++)
    {
        std::cout << check_list[i_check] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

The result is:
0x7f9506008804
0x7f9506008804
0x7f9506008804
0x7f9506008804
0x7f9506008804
0 0 0 0 1 

I noticed that to pass a &(check_list[i_check]) may be incorrect when using the capture list [&]. This r-value &(check_list[i_check]) may exceed the survival period when the final wrapped function is called. I am really confused about the behaviour of my code. I am expecting a "dangling pointer" when trying to call the wrapped function, however, this does not happen.
To make it short, I am wondering how the r-value &(check_list[i_check]) captured in the lambda expression works, making all VoidFunctionWrapper instances change the same variable's value.

"I am expecting a "dangling pointer"...." Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

Using dangling reference is UB, and with UB, anything can happen, even "seems to work".

Essentially, don't expect anything from a program with UB. See Consistency of undefined behavior for a fixed compiler and Why is the phrase: "undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything it wants" true?

Also, a value that "goes away" doesn't have to go away immediately. Sometimes the dangling pointer/reference just happens to refer to the old value (for a while).

If you do want a higher chance of detecting undefined behaviour like this, you can make use of your compiler's sanitizers (specifically address sanitizer here).

The real lesson here - and it's an important one - is to truly understand what Undefined Behavior is.  When you put Undefined Behavior in your code, you must stop all "I am expecting" and stop all "I am wondering how it works".

@DrewDormann Thanks! I am going to take this lesson.

@chris What you said makes sense. I'll try that. Thank you!

@BoP I think it might be kind of default "compiler behaviour" which may differ for gcc, msvc or something else. Thank you for your attention.

@user12002570 That's right. Maybe it is just that you don't use anything you can not predict. Thank you for your time.

@Jarod42 That's right. Thank you for noticing me that.

You do have dangling references, and the use of them has undefined behaviour. What you are surprised by is the particular symptoms of the undefined behaviour.
C++ is not a safe language. Experiencing undefined behaviour does not mean the program crashes, it means that you cannot rely on the rules of C++ to predict the program's behaviour. Anything can happen.
